# How to get simple dopar in R example working

Tags: r, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I'm trying to get a simple `dopar` example working so I can parallelize some very expensive cross validation calculations.  When I run the following code, my result array `r` is filled with `NA`:

```
library(doParallel)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)


data1.1 = 1:9   # mean(data1.1) = 5
data1.2 = 2:10  # mean(data1.2) = 6
data1.3 = 3:11  # mean(data1.3) = 7
data2.1 = 4:12  # mean(data2.1) = 8
data2.2 = 5:13  # mean(data2.2) = 9
data2.3 = 6:14  # mean(data2.3) = 10
data3.1 = 7:15  # mean(data3.1) = 11
data3.2 = 8:16  # mean(data3.2) = 12
data3.3 = 9:17  # mean(data3.3) = 13

data_list = list("1" = list("1" = data1.1, "2" = data1.2, "3" = data1.3),
                 "2" = list("1" = data2.1, "2" = data2.2, "3" = data2.3),
                 "3" = list("1" = data3.1, "2" = data3.2, "3" = data3.3))

# parallel::detectCores()  # 16 on Ryzen 7 system
cl = parallel::makeCluster(detectCores() - 2, output = "")
# activate cluster for foreach library
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

r = array(0, c(3, 3))
for (i in 1:3) {
  r[i, ] = foreach::foreach(j = 1:length(data_list[[i]]),
                       .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
                          mean(data_list[[i]][j])
                       }
}

# stop cluster to free up resources
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

The results I'm expecting in `r` array is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    6    7
[2,]    8    9   10
[3,]   11   12   13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `r` array is not being filled because `mean` is returning an `NA`. This can be solved by adding another `[` around `j`.

```r
data1.1 = 1:9   # mean(data1.1) = 5
data1.2 = 2:10  # mean(data1.2) = 6
data1.3 = 3:11  # mean(data1.3) = 7
data2.1 = 4:12  # mean(data2.1) = 8
data2.2 = 5:13  # mean(data2.2) = 9
data2.3 = 6:14  # mean(data2.3) = 10
data3.1 = 7:15  # mean(data3.1) = 11
data3.2 = 8:16  # mean(data3.2) = 12
data3.3 = 9:17  # mean(data3.3) = 13

data_list = list("1" = list("1" = data1.1, "2" = data1.2, "3" = data1.3),
                 "2" = list("1" = data2.1, "2" = data2.2, "3" = data2.3),
                 "3" = list("1" = data3.1, "2" = data3.2, "3" = data3.3))


library(foreach)

r = array(0, c(3, 3))
for (i in 1:3) {
  r[i, ] = foreach::foreach(j = 1:length(data_list[[i]]),
                            .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
                              mean(data_list[[i]][[j]])
                            }
}
#> Warning: executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered

r
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    5    6    7
#> [2,]    8    9   10
#> [3,]   11   12   13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

If you create a helper function and run that in `foreach` it might simplify things. You can let `foreach` be the iterator of list elements, so you can skip the `for` loop. Then each worker will have a clear set of data (one list element) and function (`mean_inner_list`) to run.

```r
data1.1 = 1:9   # mean(data1.1) = 5
data1.2 = 2:10  # mean(data1.2) = 6
data1.3 = 3:11  # mean(data1.3) = 7
data2.1 = 4:12  # mean(data2.1) = 8
data2.2 = 5:13  # mean(data2.2) = 9
data2.3 = 6:14  # mean(data2.3) = 10
data3.1 = 7:15  # mean(data3.1) = 11
data3.2 = 8:16  # mean(data3.2) = 12
data3.3 = 9:17  # mean(data3.3) = 13

data_list = list("1" = list("1" = data1.1, "2" = data1.2, "3" = data1.3),
                 "2" = list("1" = data2.1, "2" = data2.2, "3" = data2.3),
                 "3" = list("1" = data3.1, "2" = data3.2, "3" = data3.3))


#----------


library(foreach)

mean_inner_list <- function(x) lapply(x, mean)

foreach(x = data_list, .combine = rbind) %dopar% mean_inner_list(x)
#> Warning: executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered
#>          1  2  3 
#> result.1 5  6  7 
#> result.2 8  9  10
#> result.3 11 12 13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Upvoted because it does work.  Am trying to avoid using lapply because in the real use case, there is lot of code where that mean function is being called. Doing things this way would require triple nesting of functions which is doable, but won't be easy to debug.

Comment: To get your original code to work add another `[` around `j`, i.e. `mean(data_list[[i]][[j]]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra . in front of dopar in your foreach statement. Try removing that and see if it fixes the problem.

Here is the updated code with the . removed:

```
library(doParallel)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)

data1.1 = 1:9   # mean(data1.1) = 5
data1.2 = 2:10  # mean(data1.2) = 6
data1.3 = 3:11  # mean(data1.3) = 7
data2.1 = 4:12  # mean(data2.1) = 8
data2.2 = 5:13  # mean(data2.2) = 9
data2.3 = 6:14  # mean(data2.3) = 10
data3.1 = 7:15  # mean(data3.1) = 11
data3.2 = 8:16  # mean(data3.2) = 12
data3.3 = 9:17  # mean(data3.3) = 13

data_list = list("1" = list("1" = data1.1, "2" = data1.2, "3" = data1.3),
                 "2" = list("1" = data2.1, "2" = data2.2, "3" = data2.3),
                 "3" = list("1" = data3.1, "2" = data3.2, "3" = data3.3))

# parallel::detectCores()  # 16 on Ryzen 7 system
cl = parallel::makeCluster(detectCores() - 2, output = "")
# activate cluster for foreach library
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

r = array(0, c(3, 3))
for (i in 1:3) {
  r[i, ] = foreach::foreach(j = 1:length(data_list[[i]]),
                       .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  mean(data_list[[i]][j])
                       }
}

# stop cluster to free up resources
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: I don't see the extra . of which you speak. Just to make sure, I copied your version and my original, did a diff and didn't see any difference besides some white space. Did your version run locally?